# web2py redirect to https function for certain pages

Tags: https, redirect, web2py

I have some controller functions (in different controllers) decorated with `@auth.requires_membership(role='manager')`. If this is an http request, I would like to make sure these (and only these) get redirected to https versions.

I've tried abstracting a function like this into a module, which I call at the start of the function in any controller which needs redirecting but web2py complains that "global name 'redirect' is not defined":

```
from gluon import current

def https_redirect() :
    request = current.request
    if not request.is_local and not request.is_https:
        redirect(URL(scheme='https', args=request.args, vars=request.vars))
```

There must be a better way of doing this. What are the recommended options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is already the built-in method `request.requires_https()` -- when called, if the current request is not over HTTPS, it redirects to the current URL with the `https` scheme.

Regarding `redirect`, that is a global defined in the web2py execution environment, so only available in models, controllers, and views. You can access it in a module via the `current` object using `current.globalenv['redirect']`.

You can also redirect by using the `HTTP` exception directly (which is what `redirect` does behind the scenes):

```
from gluon.http import HTTP
from gluon.html import URL

raise HTTP(303, location=URL(...))
```

Comment: Thanks. That's almost perfect. I'd like to redirect only if not running with `request.is_local`, so I guess I can simply do a shortcut or, e.g. `request.is_local or request.requires_https()`